# JS: Sort JSON array by two different properties, maintaining order specified in array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of JSON objects I need to sort. The array needs to be sorted by two different properties. First, the array should be alphabetically sorted by the `found` property. Second, the array should be sorted so that the `website` property descends in the same order specified in `siteOrder`.

```
var siteOrder = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'reddit', 'youtube', 'instagram'];
var data = [
    {found: 'booker', website: 'reddit'},
    {found: 'john', website: 'facebook'},
    {found: 'walter', website: 'twitter'},
    {found: 'smith', website: 'instagram'},
    {found: 'steve', website: 'youtube'},
    {found: 'smith', website: 'facebook'},
    {found: 'steve', website: 'twitter'},
    {found: 'john', website: 'instagram'},
    {found: 'walter', website: 'youtube'}
];

/* Example output: Sorted output by found, respecting the order of the websites specified
{found: 'booker', website: 'reddit'},
{found: 'john', website: 'facebook'},
{found: 'john', website: 'instagram'},
{found: 'smith', website: 'facebook'},
{found: 'smith', website: 'instagram'},
{found: 'steve', website: 'twitter'},
{found: 'steve', website: 'youtube'},
{found: 'walter', website: 'twitter'},
{found: 'walter', website: 'youtube'}
*/
```

I can alphabetically sort the by the found property using:

```
data.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.found.toUpperCase();
    var textB = b.found.toUpperCase();
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

However I do not know how to make it also respect the specified order of the websites.

Comment: You have an array of objects, not "JSON objects".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the found text is same for 2 objects, then compare the index of the website of the 2 objects in siteOrder.

```
data.sort(function (a, b) {
  var textA = a.found.toUpperCase();
  var textB = b.found.toUpperCase();
  var foundOrder = (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
  if (foundOrder === 0) {
    var indexA = siteOrder.indexOf(a.website);
    var indexB = siteOrder.indexOf(b.website);
    return (indexA < indexB) ? -1 : (indexA > indexB) ? 1 : 0;
  }
  return foundOrder;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var siteOrder = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'reddit', 'youtube', 'instagram'];
var data = [
    {found: 'booker', website: 'reddit'},
    {found: 'john', website: 'facebook'},
    {found: 'walter', website: 'twitter'},
    {found: 'smith', website: 'instagram'},
    {found: 'steve', website: 'youtube'},
    {found: 'smith', website: 'facebook'},
    {found: 'steve', website: 'twitter'},
    {found: 'john', website: 'instagram'},
    {found: 'walter', website: 'youtube'}
];

// For performance, add a property that is the index of the website in the list
data.forEach(o => o.siteIndex = siteOrder.indexOf(o.website));

// If the `found` of each object is the same, then use the index of the
// website as the sort criteria, otherwise compare the `found` props
data.sort((a, b) =>
  a.found === b.found ? a.siteIndex - b.siteIndex : a.found.localeCompare(b.found)
);

// Remove the optimization property
data.forEach(o => delete o.siteIndex);

console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var siteOrder = ["facebook", "twitter", "reddit", "youtube", "instagram"];
var data = [{
    found: "booker",
    website: "reddit"
  },
  {
    found: "john",
    website: "facebook"
  },
  {
    found: "walter",
    website: "twitter"
  },
  {
    found: "smith",
    website: "instagram"
  },
  {
    found: "steve",
    website: "youtube"
  },
  {
    found: "smith",
    website: "facebook"
  },
  {
    found: "steve",
    website: "twitter"
  },
  {
    found: "john",
    website: "instagram"
  },
  {
    found: "walter",
    website: "youtube"
  }
];

const result = data.sort((a, b) => {
  const textA = a.found.toUpperCase();
  const textB = b.found.toUpperCase();

  if (textA < textB) {
    return -1;
  } else if (textA > textB) {
    return 1;
  }

  const siteA = siteOrder.indexOf(a.website);
  const siteB = siteOrder.indexOf(b.website);

  if (siteA < siteB) {
    return -1;
  } else if (siteA > siteB) {
    return 1;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by specifying a sort handler that;

- first compares a pair of items based on the `found` field. If the items are not a match, return `-1` or `1` respectivly
- if the `found` field of each of the current items do match, then sort those item pairs in the same way (returning `-1`, `1` or `0`) based on the index of the `website` field of each item, in the `sortOrder` array

That can be implemented as shown below:

```js
var siteOrder = ['facebook', 'twitter', 'reddit', 'youtube', 'instagram'];
var data = [
    {found: 'booker', website: 'reddit'},
    {found: 'john', website: 'facebook'},
    {found: 'walter', website: 'twitter'},
    {found: 'smith', website: 'instagram'},
    {found: 'steve', website: 'youtube'},
    {found: 'smith', website: 'facebook'},
    {found: 'steve', website: 'twitter'},
    {found: 'john', website: 'instagram'},
    {found: 'walter', website: 'youtube'}
];

data.sort((itemA, itemB) => {
  
  const foundA = itemA.found.toLowerCase();
  const foundB = itemB.found.toLowerCase();
  
  /* Sort based on found (primary criteria) */
  if(foundA < foundB) return -1;
  if(foundA > foundB) return 1;
  
  /* If foundA and foundB are equivilant, sort 
  based on website (secondary criteria) */
  const websiteA = itemA.website.toLowerCase();
  const websiteB = itemB.website.toLowerCase();
  
  /* Find index of each site, relative to the siteOrder array */
  const siteA = siteOrder.indexOf(websiteA);
  const siteB = siteOrder.indexOf(websiteB);
  
  /* Sort items that have matching found values, by the index that site
  values occour in the siteOrder */
  website values in
  if(siteA < siteB) return -1;
  if(siteA > siteB) return 1;
  
  return 0;
});

console.log(data);
```